# Chinese character in environ['PATH'] cannot be recognized by cmake

Tags: python, utf-8, cmake, chinese-locale

Currently I'm trying to add a toolchain path into `os.environ['PATH']` to build my project. The path contains some Chinese chars and the cmake program just cannot recognize the path properly. Everything works fine with pure English path.

The strange thing is that I can print out the path and all the files under it using `print(os.environ['PATH'])` and `print(os.listdir(os.environ['PATH']))`, and all the Chinese characters can be displayed properly. What makes it more strange is that the cmake program resides in the same toolchain folder and can be executed without problem. So I figured that I might need to modify the makefile or maybe the system default encoding to solve the problem? The building program executed in makefile are something like `arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9...` and the error I got is `arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

Environment:
Win10-64bit
System default encoding: gb2312
Python 3.7, coding: utf-8

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use CMake with Makefile generator, then how is your problem related with Python? Also, with `VERBOSE=1` option to `make` (or `mingw32-make`, as you use MinGW), you may see exact command lines which are executed. Please, use this option and show us that **exact command line** and **exact error message** it causes.

Comment: Note: `os.environment` and `print` behaviours depends on the locale you are using, so make sure you are using the correct (and consistent locale). `cmake` also uses locale. `sudo` usually uses in a different locale. Your IDE may set a different locale. And to explicit uses locale (on other cases) in python, you should explicitly initialize `locale` function. `os.environment`, and `os.path` uses in addition some tricks (thing may be in a mixed locale, out of python control). Confusing? Yes.